# What does "si" mean in "Lui aspetta" vs. "Lui si aspetta"

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, idioms

What significance does *si* have in the two sentences?

- Lui aspetta
- Lui si aspetta

I understand **si** means himself/herself/themselves(singular).

I translate the two phrases naively as "he waits", and "he himself waits". (Or *he expects* vs. *he himself expects*) But Google Translate and Duolingo tell me the differences are actually:

- *He waits* and,
- *He expects*, respectively.

So, what language rule am I missing here?

Grazie in anticipo!

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE!

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/aspettare

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The form *aspettarsi* is formally reflexive, but it's not the same reflexive as *lavarsi* (to wash oneself): it's impossible for anybody to “wait for themselves”.

It's actually a “medial” form, which denotes “advantage”. A common case is

> mangio una mela
>
> mi mangio una mela

The latter form is sometimes mistakenly considered ungrammatical, but instead conveys the idea that I'll eat an apple and will be happy to.

Different verbs have different meaning of the medial form. The verb *aspettare* means essentially the same as *to wait for*; the medial form indeed means *to expect* in almost all meanings of English. An exception: in English one says *to expect a baby*, in Italian it is *aspettare un bambino* (not *​*aspettarsi*). Another exception: *to be expected* is rendered as *essere atteso*; in the same vein the *expected value* (in probability theory) is *valore atteso*.

The verb *attendere/attendersi* is pretty much a synonym for *aspettare/aspettarsi*.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. Lots of terms to look up. :)